# What's the adjective of "conspectus"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, derivation

> This is a well-written **conspectus** for a project.
>   Since it's very well written, it makes the project ?**conspectible**.

Apparently, *conspectible* is not recognized by the dictionaries I've checked. What is a correct choice of word in this context? Please note that I'm not looking for a synonym in this case, although it'd be nice to get some.

Comment: *Conspectus* is a pretty rare word in (American) English. And it means "summary" (*prospectus* is more common, I think), so what meaning are you going for when you try to use *conspectible*?

Comment: @Thomas Summary. Also, I prefer to use American English.   :)

Comment: @Thomas Perhaps I'm making the mistake of expressing my opinion of the project as adjectivistic epithet. Your approach is more clear, I need to add. If you put is as a reply, I'll check it as an answer, then.

Comment: I would understand ‘conspectible’ (if it did exist) as ‘possible to summarise’. So because the conspectus is well-written, it makes the project summarisable? This doesn't really make sense …

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but it strikes me that the logic of the sentence is wrong. Being well-written does not make something a good summary: something could be well-written but completely off-topic.

Comment: A good summary is clear, thorough and concise. Which qualities are you seeking to emphasize? If all, perhaps just say "It is well written".

Comment: Beware *conspectable* is a slang term unrelated to what you have in mind. Even otherwise, that form of the word would be an inflection of *conflect* (“Where finding my selfe so base a worme in such an excellent conspect, I was woonderfully astonished, and lyke one that had no spyrite.” *Hypnerotomachia The Strife of Loue in a Dreame*), **not** of *conflectus*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps rephrase to something like:

> Since it's very well written, it summarizes the project well.

Comment: -1 The question is: *What's the adjective of "conspectus"?* The OP is looking for a legitimate word in place of the questionable "conspectible."

Comment: @Kris OP asked me to post this as answer, which was previously a comment.

Comment: The OP is newer (by rep) than you, so can be unaware that a "not-an-answer" could earn down votes. Furthermore, rephrasing is a work-around (in the domain of writersSE), and not a solution. HTH. If you edit your answer to improve, I will be able to reverse my down vote, for now it's locked.

Comment: @Kris While I agree with your sharp observation, I'm also pragmatic in the sense that if a native speaker of English suggests a rephrase then, although technically not an exact answer to the question, it's still informative suggestion and needs to be respected. After all, my aim is, indirectly, to express myself in English improvedly. (Yupp, the weirdness of the last sentence is intended to exemplify my point, hihi.) That applies especially if the replier points out that the response isn't an exact answer but still tries to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no adjective associated specifically with 'conspectus'. You can form an adjective, as with virtually any noun, with a construction along the lines of 'conspectus-like'.

You may be thinking there is such a thing because of the adjective "prospective". But "prospective" isn't an adjective from "prospectus", it's from "prospect".